# Hide div when click on the image and show another one instead

Tags: html, css, angular

I have an image gallery that allows me to view the images. Each image has a div with the name of that image. When I click on the image, I want the div with the name to disappear and in its place a new div with tools will appear.

When I click outside the image, I want to get the original state, that is, the image has the name div.

Right now I can make the div with the name disappear and instead show the div with the tools, with all that div open in all images and I just want it to be just the image where I clicked. The second problem arises that when I close the modal (goal is to open a modal at the same time as the tool div appears) I try to get the original state, but I can't :(
I don't know why but in stackblitz the modal doesn't open :(

**I leave my code to understand better**

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kwjn9u)

I am using angular, if there is a more correct form and using all its potential, I am very grateful for the help

**My function**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      var toolbar = $('.ImageButtonsG').html();
      $(".d-flex").on("click", function () {
        var default_title_ele = $(this).find('.VimageText');
        var default_title = $(default_title_ele).html();
        $(default_title_ele).html(toolbar);
        $("#modalPoll").on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
          $(default_title_ele).html(default_title);
        });
      });
    });
```

Comment: Just stick to angular, If its angularJS project. Jquery is not required for your usecase

Comment: I am using normal angle, there may be a better or simpler way to get what you want without using jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do in in Angular way like this:

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ef38zc?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

.ts

```
data = [
    {
      src:
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1485963631004-f2f00b1d6606?auto=format&fit=crop&w=668&q=80",
        text:1,
        show :true
    },
    {
      src:
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1502865787650-3f8318917153?auto=format&fit=crop&w=334&q=80",
        text:2,
        show :true
    }
  ];
```

.html

```
    <div class="d-flex flex-column">
            <div (mouseout)="img.show = true" *ngFor="let img of data">
                <a>
                    <img [src]="img.src"
          class="img-fluid Vimages" (click)="img.show = false">
                    <div class="VimageText G1" *ngIf="img.show"> {{img.text}}</div>
                </a>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Sounds like a good solution, but how do I get the tools div to appear when I click on the image? And by clicking outside the image is it possible to have the initial state again? The div with the name appears

Comment: Yes, you can get back to initial state by using focus out method on your div, then you can reset your flags

Comment: Yes, you can add `(mouseout)="img.show = true" ` . Added it in the demo. Check

Comment: For the tools div, you can just add another property in the json and handle it in the same way